# App engine+Postgresql getting "Connection refused" error

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine, connection

I am a newbie trying to deploy a toy django app on the standard App engine and I am getting the following errors.

**Running App locally**

My app **runs properly** locally with the cloud SQL when I use 127.0.0.1 or Public IP as 'HOST' address. However, I get a this error if I use GCP connection name like this:

```
'HOST':  '/cloudsql/asim800:us-central1:django-mysql-1'

OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/cloudsql/asim800:us-central1:django-mysql-1'
```

**Running App on GAE**

1. Using HOST='/cloudsql/asim800:us-central1:django-mysql-1', I get this error
   2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)" - not sure why I am getting 'localhost' in the error but there seems to be something wrong with translating Google connection name to host and port information.
2. Using public IP for mysql instance on the GAE results in timeout.

My settings.py looks like this

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                'HOST': '/cloudsql/asim800:us-central1:django-mysql-1', 
                'NAME': 'myproject',
                'USER': 'pblogsu',
                'PASSWORD': '****',
        }
    }
```

I can see them correctly in the following log:

{'database': 'myproject',
'host': '/cloudsql/asim800:us-central1:django-app1',
'password': 'pblogsu',
'user': 'hidden'}

I have enabled Google Cloud SQL API. Not sure how to debug Google connection name mapping to host/port addresses.
I have seen similar problem reported like here (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/870) but none of the suggestions have helped me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I have edited my question substantially. Earlier I had used postgesql with very similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out that one of the service account (associated with GAE) needed to be added in the IAM & Admin> IAM and then given Cloud sql.Client role.

It sounds like an easy fix with the hindsight but it took a lot of digging in to resolve the issue. I had suspected that there may be a permission issue but I wasn't sure which account needs to be added. I got my first clue after I saw this error in the logs:

```
"CloudSQL warning: your action is needed to update your application and avoid potential disruptions. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview for additional details: ensure that the account has access to "asim800:us-central1:django-mysql-1" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during createEphemeral for asim800:us-central1:django-mysql-1: googleapi: Error 403: The client is not authorized to make this request., notAuthorized"
```

Thanks for your help. I'll be happy add any details if someone else run into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters `unix_socket_directories` and `port` on the PostgreSQL server. For your connection attempt to work

- the server has to run on the same machine as the client
- `cloudsql/asim800:us-central1:django-app1` has to be in `unix_socket_directories`
- `port` has to be 5432

Comment: Since I am working with django I am not sure if I have access to unix_socket_directories directly. Interesting question is how to make sure that the server is running on the same machine as app engine since I am working on Google Cloud. I also have tried MySQL on GCP but getting similar error. Thanks

Comment: Then use a TCP connection rather than one via Unix sockets.

Comment: Exactly, I was hoping that I'd get a TCP conn by using HOST: '/cloudsql/asim800:us-central1:django-app1'. I also tried public IP address but that results in connection timeout. I can connect to mysql from my local machine using the above HOST but not sure how to get it working when my app is running on the GCP App engine. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: Anything that starts with a slash is interpreted as a directory that contains Unix sockets.